# Handling arbitrary union with power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

$$\bigcup \{\mathscr P X\,|\,X \in \mathscr A\} \subseteq \mathscr P \bigcup \mathscr A$$

While trying to prove the above statement I stucked on some point.
$$x\in\bigcup\{\mathscr P X\,|\,X \in \mathscr A\} \iff (\exists X \in \mathscr A)(x \in \mathscr P X) \iff (\exists X \in \mathscr A)(x \subseteq X)$$
$$x \in \mathscr P\bigcup \mathscr A \iff x \subseteq \bigcup \mathscr A \iff (\exists X \in \mathscr A)(x \subseteq X)$$
So I got $\bigcup\{\mathscr P X\,|\,X \in \mathscr A\} = \mathscr P\bigcup \mathscr A$. It seems my argument leads to a wrong result. But what is wrong with my reasoning?

Edit: I found $x \subseteq \bigcup \mathscr A \iff (\exists X \in \mathscr A)(x \subseteq X)$ is not true but $x \subseteq \bigcap \mathscr A \iff (\forall X \in \mathscr A)(x \subseteq X)$ is true. Can anyone confirm if this is correct?

Comment: $x \subseteq \bigcap \mathscr A \iff (\forall X \in \mathscr A)(x \subseteq X)$ is true.

Comment: It might be reassuring to know that $\bigcup \mathscr{A}\subseteq x \iff (\forall X\in \mathscr{A})(X\subseteq x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x \subseteq \bigcup \mathscr A \iff (\exists X \in \mathscr A)(x \subseteq X)$ is simply false, one can come up  with very simple counter examples, just think about it. Your edit is correct.

Comment: I was writing this answer before I saw the edit, now I see that the OP has solved their own problem.